# Complex slider incrementation

Tags: javascript, slider

I'm trying to create a slider that increment this way:

[image: slider]

I first started doing a logarithmic slider but it actually didn't match the required labels. I can't figure out how to achieve this. Any ideas?

Complexity is that incrementation is changing during the slider progression: 5 -> 10, 10 -> 100, 500 -> 1000, etc.

Here is a demo slider you can play with: http://jsfiddle.net/jdefcswv/2/

Thank you!

(for some reason SO wants me to put some code in here so...)

```
<html></html>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I add a function `Converter`. They use the slider value like a global progress and define between which steps the have to calculate the value.
You add step by `addStep(progress, stepValue)`, `progress` must be a positive value.

Currently the progress between two step are linear, but that's a good start ^^.

http://jsfiddle.net/jdefcswv/3/

Comment: That's exactly what I wanted to do! :)
Thank you very much!